# Setting up for Time table application. change text view using string

Tags: android, timetable

Setting up for Time Table application.

I'm trying to make time table application.
My layout is table layout and have almost 100 text view.

My layout is like this : 
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37032956/57057813-8e77bb00-6ce6-11e9-9917-84064d67adf7.JPG

I take a value from SQLite as a string type and using this value I want to edit my TextView.

But here is my problem :

Should I initialize all almost 100 TextView?

and how select a certain text view in table layout using String type?

or any recommendation layout to make time table?

Comment: Use dynamic TextView using for loop  @Dyki

Comment: Thank you! I am changing to code. And trying to make with grid view. @g.brahmaDatta

Comment: I solved this problem with dynamic textview and getResources().getIdentifier() method.